# preg replace for needed value

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I use coordinates for shops and manually add the coordinates as lang and long to database. Sometimes by mistake, approving the coordinate.

Let me exlain by an example.

For example;
Lang is `33.4534543543` .But by mistake sometimes i push keyboard and it becomes like,

```
33.4534543543<
```

or
    33.4534543543,
or
    ,(space)33.4534543543<

How can I get only the 33.4534543543?

Comment: Simple case: `/\d*\.?\d+/g`

Comment: what have you tryed so far? why are you typing those manually? cpoy/paste?

Comment: "lang and long"? Don't you mean "lat and lon"?

Comment: @meagar don't know how I missed that. Nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## preg_match_all

To find matches from a string containing multiple matches, you would use `preg_match_all`:

```
$strings = "33.4534543543<
33.4534543543,
, 33.4534543543<";
$pattern = "!(\d+\.\d+)!";

preg_match_all($pattern,$strings,$matches);

print_r($matches[0]);
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => 33.4534543543
    [1] => 33.4534543543
    [2] => 33.4534543543
)
```

## preg_match

To find the match from a single string you could use `preg_match`.

```
$string = "33.4534543543<";
$pattern = "!(\d+\.\d+)!";

if(preg_match($pattern,$string,$match)){
print($match[0]);
}
```

**Output**

```
33.4534543543
```

## preg_replace

To replace anything that is not what you want in your existing string you would use `preg_replace`:

```
$string = preg_replace('![^\d.]!','',$string);
```

An example:

```
$strings = "33.4534543543<
33.4534543543,
, 33.4534543543<";

$strings_exp = explode("\n",$strings);

$output = '';
foreach($strings_exp as $string){
$output.= "String '$string' becomes ";
$new_string = preg_replace('![^0-9.]!','',$string);
$output.= "'$new_string'\n";
}

echo $output;
```

**output**

```
String '33.4534543543<' becomes '33.4534543543'
String '33.4534543543,' becomes '33.4534543543'
String ', 33.4534543543<' becomes '33.4534543543'
```

Answer (score 0):

Sound like you want to do a `preg_match`: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/z6q-a1d

```php
$old_vals = array(
    '33.4534543543<',
    '33.4534543543,',
    ', 33.4534543543<'
);

$new_vals = array();

foreach ($old_vals as $val) {
    preg_match('(\d*\.?\d+)',$val, $match);
    array_push($new_vals, $match[0]);
}

print_r($new_vals);
```

**Output**

```
Array (
    [0] => 33.4534543543,
    [1] => 33.4534543543,
    [2] => 33.4534543543
)
```